# Redirect to https + www everywhere

Tags: apache, redirect, https, virtualhost

I want my site to use "https://www" everywhere. non-www to www and non-https to https. Unfortunately I'm getting **www.example.come redirected you too many times** error.

my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "D:/www"
    ServerName www.example.come

    <Directory "D:/www">
        Options -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order Allow,Deny 
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L] 


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.come

    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.come/
</VirtualHost>
```

If i didn't include below lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

It will redirect: **example.com** > **https://www.example.com**

but wont redirect **www.example.com** won't be redirect to **https**.

Comment: Can you show us the https (`<VirtualHost *:443>`) config?

Comment: @DusanBajic Am i doing wrong? i don't have a <VirtualHost *:443> config

Comment: Does `https://www.example.com` work if you try to access it directly? (if it works, check content of all *.conf files in your conf/ and conf.d/ folders)